# SIlverlight 3 out-of-browser high DPI window size problem

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-3.0, dpi, out-of-browser

My Silverlight 3 application looks perfect in and out-of-browser with DPI setting in Windows XP set to Normal size (96 DPI). After changing DPI settings to Large size (120 DPI) the application looks the same in browser but scales up out-of-browser.

The problem is that when running out-of-browser the hosting window size stays the same regardless of DPI setting. So only part of the application GUI is visible with 120 DPI.

Is there any way to adjust OOB hosting window size or maybe disable scaling of application with high DPI?

Comment: A little bit of a punt here, but try setting enableAutoZoom to false.

Comment: neableAutoZoom does the job, it disables scaling of application.

Comment: Post an anwser to you question if that worked and mark it as solved.

Answer (score 0):

take a look at Pete Browns take on this:

http://10rem.net/blog/2012/02/07/creating-big-silverlight-windows-and-getting-monitor-resolutions-and-positions-with-pinvoke